# How in joomla with API with AJAX get field "Editor" for form?

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla3.0, tinymce-4, joomla-extensions

Insert this $code in module,

```html
 
<form ...>
<?= JEditor::getInstance($name_editor)->display($namefield, $valuefield, '100%', 'auto', 10, 4, TRUE, $idfield, NULL, NULL,$paramsEditor);  ?>
<input .../>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I’ll paste this code into the Joomla module, everything works fine, the WYSIWYG editor is loaded on the site. It has everything, a panel, buttons for boldness, size, indentation, etc.
But when the module works in AJAX mode, then when loading the form into the page, instead of the WYSIWYG editor, the usual        `<TEXTAREA>`        is displayed, next to the button is "Turn off editor". If you click on the "Turn Off Editor" button, nothing happens.
.
In my module there is a setting for choosing the type of editors        `"TynyEditor", "CodeMirror", "ArkEditor"`        . After choosing the type of editor and saving the settings, before the editor worked fine        `"JEditor::getInstance($name_editor)->displays()"`        without AJAX. But how to use Joomla API to display the Editor through Ajax page?

Comment: Sounds like you need to escape your code somehow - but I'm from the question review queue & just here to let you know you should post the error message everytime so we can see what's wrong to answer questions.

Comment: If you render the editor with Ajax, you might need to initiate the editors javascript functionality, since the html code appeared after the javascript looked for editors to enhance. I am not sure how or where to initiate an editor manually.

Comment: Yes. I have already done so. But alas. I launched JS only for TinyMCE. But if I need a different editor, then I need to run a completely different script. And if my module is sold. Then the editor selected in the settings may turn out to be completely unpredictable. Need JS which is universal from JoomlaCore itself. But I did not find this.